# How to add multiple commands in the same python file in discordpy

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been following this Discord.py tutorial by Robotic Nation, and I've been wondering how to add multiple commands into a single python file.
Here is my code:

```
import discord 

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.command()
async def repeat(ctx, *args):
    for arg in args:
        await ctx.send(arg)

@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
    name = str(ctx.guild.name)
    description = str(ctx.guild.description)
    owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
    id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    region = str(ctx.guild.region)
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)
    icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = name + " Server Information",
        description = description,
        color=discord.Color.dark_red()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run('[Bot Token]')
```

(Link to Video Playlist Here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJXEdhN0Tc3LRT716enS1LcY4OF8vg1VA)

I have tried adding a `client.command()` and then adding my new command below that, but whenever I run the file, the `.repeat` command will work fine, but when I try to use `.server` the terminal will say

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "server" is not found
```

However, if both commands are in seperate files, they work ok, but I want to be able to use both commands without having to stop one file from running, then start the other to use it.

I'm very new to bot developing with Discordpy, so thanks for helping!

Library Used: discord.py 1.4.1
Python Interpreter: Python 3.8.5 [32 bit]

Comment: make sure to save the code and run the new code, that should work

Comment: Did you rerun the file after adding the `.server` command?

Comment: This is an error on your end. It works fine for me and nothing should be wrong.

Comment: @Poojan OK, so this is really weird, I've saved the file, terminated the program and then re-run it all before, but just now, when I started up Visual Studio it worked lol. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Like that, since they all are functions, you can just stack them.

````
import discord 

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")


#________________________________________
@client.command()
async def yourcommandnamehere(ctx):
    await ctx.send("random text")
#_______________________________________________

@client.command()
async def repeat(ctx, *args):
    for arg in args:
        await ctx.send(arg)

@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
    name = str(ctx.guild.name)
    description = str(ctx.guild.description)
    owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
    id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    region = str(ctx.guild.region)
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)
    icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = name + " Server Information",
        description = description,
        color=discord.Color.dark_red()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run('[Bot Token]')```
````